# A renderflex overflowed by 6.2 pixel on the bottom

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Using flutter for mobile application development, while opening keyboard this error comes, any suggestion.

Comment: A suggestion is to wrap the widget in a ScrollView

Comment: Including code would be helpful

Comment: helloooooo guys, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53809904/6224209) :)

Answer (score 0):

This bug may be due to using **InputDecoration** with LabelText, Please Try Replacing the LabelText with the Hint Text, or wrap everything within the Scroll